# Put questions on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

can you tell me how can I put questions and get more answers ! what I should do to get more interaction with my posts ! waiting for hours and days maybe months to get an answer or comment is not good ... Really I  want some advices , thanks in advance